# CRM 365 - OnSave Handler not executing

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am developing for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365.

In the formulars you are able to place javascript libraries that can provide callbacks methods for certain events, such as OnLoad and OnSave.

In CRM I provided a javascript library with a function called "EntryPoint" which takes a parameter "executionContext". I set up this library and function for the OnSave method of my formular (which formular is irrelevant, but it is the edit contact formular) and checked the mark for "passing in the execution context as first parameter".

For the sake of clarity here my method structure:

```js
function EntryPoint(executionContext){
    console.log("Execute");
}
```

Outside of the method I have another:

```js
console.log("File loaded");
```

The problem I face is:
My library gets loaded everytime, but the method "EntryPoint" isn't invoked everytime a user saves the formular.
It is absolutely random to the formular to invoke my method or not. I reloaded the page about 20 times, changed the state of a two option field, and pressed save. 14 times it got invoked, 6 times it didn't.

So this behavior is not reproducible and completely arbitrary.

Did anyone face the same problem and got a solution for this?

I spent hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: You wrote "I reloaded page 20 times" and that this function is registered on "OnSave" of the form. I don't understand why are you reloading page to test "OnSave" method. Did you mean that you click "Save" button 20 times? The OnSave event will be fired only if you changed something on the form

Comment: @Pawel Gradecki Sorry of course I mean I reloaded the page 20 times, changed the state of a two option field, and pressed save on the lower right corner.

Comment: Ok so if you reload and the function is working, is it working every time you change something and click save? And if it's not working, it just never fires? And also - are you sure that it's not firing? Can you put "debugger" in your function, run Developer tools and check saving again to make sure it's really not firing? Are there any bugs in the console?

Comment: Yea well I can clearly say that it gets invoked sometimes and sometimes not since I already used a debugger as you suggest and the breakpoint did not fire.

Comment: Also, the data gets saved to the server since I see a network request inside the network module of the developer options

Comment: What browser do you use? How does it work in another one?

Comment: @jcjr I am using chrome and tbh I didnt think about using another browser (shame). Next week I will try it and let you know what I get. Thanks for the approach